# Linq - master details table - filter by lookup table

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a simple master detail scenario (like course and students with an 1..n foreign key association) and i query the course table and use the entity framework to access the students as well (via lazy loading):

```
    Dim db As New EFEntities()
    Dim x = db.COURSES.SingleOrDefault(Function(f) f.ID= 101)
    'Access Master
    Console.WriteLine(x.COURSENAME.ToString())
    'Access Detail
    For Each e In x.STUDENTS
        Console.WriteLine(e.STUDENTNAME)
    Next
```

But now I want only the students returned who have a certain value (call it CATEGORY) assigned. The values that are valid are stored in an look up table. So i think i would need an subselect like `WHERE STUDENTS.CATEGORY IN (SELECT VALUE FROM ANYTABLE)` but i'm not shure how to add this to my existing query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) like this:

```vb
Dim catIds = ... 'Get your category Ids here.
Dim students = From s In context.Students _
               Where catIds.Contains(s.CategoryId) Select s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var catIds= new List<long>{cat1Id, cat2Id};
var filteredStudents = x.Students.Where(s=>catIds.Any(s.Category.CategoryId));
```

In C#, you'll need something similar.

Comment: In EF, this will throw "Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."

Comment: In that case you can use a list of category ids to compare.